# pandas dataframe combining

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a database which contains 2 tables. I'd like to get all the data from both tables into single dataframe. In both tables there is a time column on which I'd like to sort the data after the combining.

```
df1=pd.read_sql("Select * from table1")
df2=pd.read_sql("Select * from table2")
```

What is the best way to combine df1 and df2 to a single dataframe ordered by time column?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to join (merge) data frames (inner, outer, left, right)](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1299871/6381711)

Answer (score 1):

Do you mean by `concat` and `sort_values`:

```
print(pd.concat([df1, df2]).sort_values('time'))
```

Comment: yes, but I don't see the sort method available

Comment: @user1977050 Use `sort_values`